# Delete a previously added rule in ufw

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, firewall, ufw

I created a firewall rule for an application and put into `/etc/ufw/applications.d`, added that rule with command

```
sudo ufw allow MyApp
```

but now I cannot delete it. When I do

```
sudo ufw delete MyApp
```

it just prints the list of available commands like my command was invalid, which is what it probably was, but I don't know any other ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to delete the rule, the syntax is

```
sudo ufw delete allow MyApp
```

see: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW